# force Toplevel Widget on top of root widget

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I have a tkinter app with a Toplevel widget that I want to create when the window is starting. The issue I have is that the Toplevel window always ends up behind the main window. Is there a way to force it in front of the root window?

Comment: Make the toplevel a transient window of the root window.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @acw1668's comment, here's an example of how to create a transient window that sits on top of the root window. Note that a transient window will only have a close button `[X]`, and no minimize / maximize buttons.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.new_window_button = ttk.Button(
            self,
            text='Open New Window',
            command=self.new_window,
        )
        self.new_window_button.pack()

    def new_window(self):
        self.dialog_window = tk.Toplevel(self)
        self.dialog_window.transient(self)  # place this window on top of the root window


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

One important thing to consider is that you might want to prevent the user from interacting with the root window while the dialog is open. Otherwise, in the case of this example, the user could keep clicking the button and spawning new windows. You can do this by calling `grab_set()` on the dialog (thanks @acw1668 for reminding me)

```
def new_window(self):
    self.dialog_window = tk.Toplevel(self)
    self.dialog_window.transient(self)  # place this window on top of the root window
    self.dialog_window.grab_set()  # hold focus
```

Comment: Using `self.dialog_window.grab_set()` is more safe than disabling and enabling the root window.  In case there is something wrong after disabling the root window, then you can never get back to the root window.

Comment: @acw1668 you're right, and I've done that in the past...not sure why that escaped me here! I'll make that edit.

Comment: @acw1668 Now I'm remembering where I picked up this `attributes` hack. I had to use it on a dialog window that also popped up a `tkinter.messagebox` since the messagebox window doesn't allow for `grab_set()` - at least I'm not totally insane...